# How do I script screen to create multiple windows?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I have a little problem with screen.

I wanted to launch several servers in a screen session, so I made a little script designed to to have one server per window.

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -dmS servers
screen -S servers -t http -p 0 sh -c "cd /servers/start/httpo ; run.sh"
screen -S servers -t sql -p 1 sh -c "cd /servers/start/sql ; run.sh"
...
```

But it's not working right - the sessions are created, but all the commands start on the first window.

I read the man page, but I still can't find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -dmS servers -T xterm -t "http" sh -c 'cd /servers/start/httpo;run.sh'

screen -T xterm -S "servers" -X screen screen -t "sql" sh -c 'cd /servers/start/sql;run.sh'
...
```

The "-T xterm" switch isn't really necessary, unless you plan to use curses-based programs from inside the screen (mc, less, etc.).